# Cocos2d -> Swift SpriteKit - CCLabelAtlas charmap functionality

Tags: ios, swift, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-kit

Firstly, I apologise if this has been asked before.. I'm still very finding my feet with coding and im not entirely sure I'd be looking at the right answer if it was right in front me, hence me giving in and posting here for help!

A few years ago, I stuck my feet into cocos2d for a while and there was a very useful way of adding your own fonts to labels and I wondered if the same thing could be done in sprite kit?

Looking here, this is how it would be setup in my cocos2d project from years ago:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello World",;
myLabelAtlas = [CCLabelAtlas labelWithString:myString charMapFile:@"My_Font.png" itemWidth:16/2 itemHeight:24/2 startCharMap:'.'];
```

I'm trying to repeat this process in swift with Sprite Kit, using the same 'My_Font.png' file [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crHYg.png)

Is this even possible??

(Many thanks in advance and sorry again for the n00b question!)

Comment: [Adding your custom fonts for iOS](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a `SKLabelNode` to add a label to a scene.  The link Wang Yudong gave you [here](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/) shows you how to add your fonts to your project so that you can get them as a `UIFont`.  At the top of your `GameScene.swift` you want to put this code (class given so you know where I'm talking about):

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var label = SKLabelNode(text: "Hello World")
```

Now the `SKLabelNode` takes a `String!` as the font name to use.  So we do something like this in `didMoveToView` (replace `<your font name>` with your font's name):

```
label.fontName = "<your font name>" // The font's name
label.fontSize = 18 // The size of your font
label.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor() // The color to use for your font
self.addChild(label) // Add the label to the scene
```

Keep in mind that you need the font's name after it is in the system.  Sometimes font names aren't what they appear to be.  To scan through all of the font names (and find the name to use for your font), use this code (this is from the link, just in case the link goes away at some point):

```
for family: String in UIFont.familyNames()
{
     print("\(family)")
     for names: String in UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(family)
     {
         print("== \(names)")
     }
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to use a `.png` for your font (I also don't know if your are still using that font).  There may be an online generator somewhere that converts `.png` font's into a more common format.  But once you have it converted (into something like `.otf` or `.ttf`), you can drop your font into your project (on the left side where your files are listed).  From there, you add it to a list of fonts provided by the application in the `info.plist` file (should be buried in Supporting Files).

Now your application should have your font in, and have a `SKLabelNode`.  If you need to, you can set the text of it later on.

Comment: Hi Mate, thanks for responding.... although this hasnt quite answered my question, its very useful to know the steps for adding a standard font. Digging into this more, I believe its more of bitmap font / photofont that i'm looking to display, hence the .png file. Going to dig around a bit more and see if I can find the answer

Comment: @Spoonfed  Okay, doing a bit more looking into this, it appears somebody has created a variant of the `SKLabelNode` that handles bitmap fonts.  You can find it [here](http://www.bmglyph.com/tutorials-spritekit-bitmap-font/), with a tutorial.  Let me know if that works.